# session duration settings are not adopted in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

My intention is, to not lose a session, after being inactive for 20mins on a page, or closing all tabs. I want the session to remain according to my requirements.

How I proceed:

- created a file "sessionSettings.php" where I set up the duration, see code below
- included it in every file where it is needed, before session_start();

But it somehow does not adapt, and the session gets removed as usual behavior.

*Thanks in advance!*

**sessionSettings.php**

```
<?php
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 week
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 week
session_set_cookie_params(604800);
```

Comment: Did you see this note in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)?     Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.

Comment: @Nick : I get it. Since I don't have control of the php.ini, I alter the settings through a file. My question would be: Do I need to include that sessionSettings file in any page, or just where I call the session_start() function?

Comment: You can actually supply those options directly to `session_start` e.g. `session_start(['save_path' => 'some path']);` but otherwise yes, it should only be needed in pages where you call `session_start`

Comment: @Nick I might have forgot it somewhere. I will check it in a minute. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick The PHPSESSID cookie expires at the date I wish. But I realized there is another cookie called "SERVERID123", which expires by "Session". I don't get where it is coming from? My application session somehow listens to that cookie. I have tested it locally too, there it works very well. And there is only one cookie "PHPSESSID". So what is wrong? It seems like it's the servers fault

Comment: I don't know where that would come from. PHP sessions only use one cookie which defaults to the `PHPSESSID` name (although you can change it using `session_name()`), and you already have that. But maybe there's some code running another parallel session with `session.name` set to `SERVERID123`? If it is coming from PHP you should be able to find a file called `sess_` and the value of the cookie in the session file storage directory

Comment: @Nick unfortunately I don't have access to that directory, since it is a webhosting package. I don't think the code is wrong, but the settings on the server might be a bit different, since it works for me locally. But even if the session cookie name from that server is altered, why would it create the default one "PHPSESSID" as well?
Edit: Can I somehow find out, if the servers php session settings are altered, to the default one?

Comment: You could try looking at the output of `session_name()` as that would tell you the name that PHP is using for the session cookie. But since `SERVERID123` is presumably coming from some other piece of code I doubt that will show anything (i.e. I expect it will be `PHPSESSID`). You could also try `ini_get('session.name')` before you set it in `sessionSettings.php` to see if there's something there then... Without access to the server this is pretty hard to debug...

Comment: @Nick I did return the session_name(), and it is indeed PHPSESSID. I really have no idea where SERVERID is coming from, since it does not exist locally, with the exact same code. It is just on the server. Might it be that this kills the other cookie?

Comment: @Nick I just checked again. The client session cookie value, doesn't change! So it must be a problem on the server, where the session reference get removed somehow.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas in that case. Without complete access to the server it will be hard to debug. Sorry...

Comment: Ok no worries. Thank you anyway!